# Is it possible to register a user with phone and link an email account at the same time?

Tags: firebase-authentication, swiftui

I am trying to link an email and password to an account created with phone auth directly after the user is created. However, when I look in the firebase console, only the phone auth was registered. Is it possible to implement this?

```
func register () {
    
    let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: self.verificationCode, verificationCode: self.code)
                              
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (result, error) in
                                  
        if error != nil{
                                      
            self.alertMessage = (error?.localizedDescription)!
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
        }
        
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
                                  
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("statusChange"), object: nil)
        
        let credentialTwo = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: self.email, password: self.password)
        
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.link(with: credentialTwo) { (authResult, error) in
            
            if error != nil{
                                          
                self.alertMessage = (error?.localizedDescription)!
                self.alert.toggle()
                return
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding two functions and putting them one after the other in a button but that does not work either.

```
Group {
        
        if (self.session.session != nil) {
            
            if user?.metadata.creationDate != user?.metadata.lastSignInDate {
                
                AppView()
                
            } else {
                
                EmailRegisterView()
                
            }
            
           
            
        } else {
        
            OnBoardingView()
        
        }
```

}

The above code works to take the user to the email register screen but if they log out on the first day they created the account it will also take them to that screen which can cause problems.

Comment: Creating and linking accounts are two separate operations.  It's not possible to do them at the same time.  You might want to check the results of the API for errors to find out if there was an error and what the problem was.  If there was no errors, then you can assume it worked correctly.  If it didn't work, you should explain in more detail what didn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson then what is the best way to create a user with phone and then link the email? Because I'm having trouble sending the user to "add email" screen after they've registered. Since after I register it automatically takes the user to the main app screen. I need to send them to "add email screen" only if they are a new user and they just registered. I have added the code above.